# Using X11/Xlib.h on Mac OS X Mountain Lion (or Later) and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos, x11, osx-lion

So I've done some googling and I need XQuartz installed in order to develop for Mac using X11. I'm writing a simple *.dylib that makes the application calling it remove its window decorations. This is an extension I've written for GameMaker Studio 1.4 and 2. I got it working on Linux as an *.so.

My question is, if the end user doesn't have XQuartz installed on their Mac, or X11 on their Linux, will they not be able to remove window decorations using the compiled library (*.dylib/*.so)? I'm aware XQuartz/X11 is needed to be installed in order to build the *.dylib/*.so, but I need to know if after those libraries are successfully compiled, if the end user still needs XQuartz/X11 installed just like me as the developer of those libraries needs those installed.

It's really hard to explain this question, and I hope I made it clear what I'd like to know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user doesn't have XQuartz installed on their computer, they can't run X11 applications, so they won't have any X11 windows to remove decorations from.

Removing the titlebar from a native macOS window is a completely different process, and doesn't involve XQuartz or X11 at all.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will further investigate how to achieve this in OS X.